# Bind required attribute (asterisk) to parent's form group validators in nested reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In this example using a nested Angular reactive form group, how can I bind the `[required]` attribute of `myChildFormControl` (see `TODO`) in a dynamic way based on whether `myChildFormControl` in the parent component has the `Validators.required` validator applied (due to `setChildRequired()` calls)?

One solution that could work is adding an `@Input isRequired` to the child component and updating that input in calls to `setChildRequired()`, but that seems like duplicating effort that reactive forms should provide.

**Child Form Template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myChildFormGroup">
  <input formControlName="myChildFormControl" [required]="TODO" />
</form>
```

**Child Form Component:**

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-child-form',
  templateUrl: './my-child-form.component.html'
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyChildForm),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyChildForm),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class MyChildForm implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  myChildFormGroup: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myChildFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      myChildFormControl: []
    });
  }
...
```

**Parent Form Template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myParentFormGroup">
  <app-my-child-form formControlName="myChildFormControl" />
</form>
```

**Parent Form Component:**

```
...
export class MyParentForm implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  myParentFormGroup: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myParentFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      myChildFormControl: []
    });
  }

  setChildRequired(isRequired: boolean) {
    const childForm = this.myParentFormGroup.get('myChildFormControl');
    if(isRequired) {
        childForm.setValidators(Validators.required);
    } else {
        childForm.clearValidators();
    }
  }
...
```